# Form values are not submitting into wamp server database with php (server -side ) validations

Tags: php

This file is the action file .When user submits wrong values , it heads back to the file named vform.php and asks user the correct input. But for me , after entering correct values and clicking on register , neither values are entering into wamp db, nor showing successful message. below is the code for adding values into db. after successful validation , it heads toregsuccess.php where it shows registration successful message. I don't know what exactly is the reason why values are not entering into db .

```
    <?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        include("DBConnection.php"); // include the connection object from the 
        DBConnection.php
        if ($_POST['submit']) 
        { 
          $inFullname = trim($_POST["name"]);
          $inEmail = trim($_POST["email"]);
          $inPhone = trim($_POST["phonenumber"]);
          $_SESSION['valid_name']=$inFullname;
          $_SESSION['valid_email']=$inEmail;
          $_SESSION['valid_phone']=$inPhone;
         if( !preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z' ]+)$/",$inFullname) ||!preg_match('',$inEmail) || !preg_match('',$inPhone) ){
           if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/",$inFullname)){
              $_SESSION['valid_name']=$inFullname;
                    }else {
                        $_SESSION['name_error'] = "enter valid name";
                    }
                    if(preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A- 
                     Za-z]{2,4})$/",$inEmail)){
                        $_SESSION['valid_email']=$inEmail;
                    } else{
                        $_SESSION['mail_error'] = "enter valid mail";
                    }
                    if(preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/",$inPhone)){
                        $_SESSION['valid_phone']=$inPhone;
                    } else{
                        $_SESSION['phone_error'] = "enter valid phone number";
                    }
                    header('Location: vform.php'); 
                    die();
                }
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO DETAILS(NAME,EMAIL,PHONENUMBER) VALUES(?,?,?)"); //Fetching all the records with input credentials
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $inFullname,$inEmail,$inPhone); //Where s indicates string type. You can use i-integer, d-double
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->affected_rows;

    $stmt -> close();
    $db -> close(); 
    if($result > 0) {header("location: RegSuccess.php");} // user will be taken to the success page 
    else{   echo 'Oops. Something went wrong. Please try again <a href="vform.php">Try Login</a>';}
}
?>
```

Comment: Does that comment on line 3 really finish on the next line?

Comment: Could the lack of any data in your database be due to the fact that there is no code in this script to access the database in any way let alone inserting or updating it?

Comment: `DBConnection.php`   could be the problem

Comment: Welcome. Where exactly are your saving your data to your database in that code?

Comment: *neither values are entering into wamp db, nor showing successful message*  That is because you don't have anycode that handles this

Comment: Hahaha I think we are all on the same page here guys :)

Comment: Also I dont see any ___success message___ in this code either

Comment: Ok, lets give the guy 10 minutes to add the missing code to the question

Comment: Sorry here is the missing code

Comment: That would be more useful if you added it to yuor question using the edit link under the question box

Comment: yes updated please see the code